# Cannot Install CNTK

Tags: pip, cntk

When I try to install CNTK using pip, it gives me the following error - `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cntk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cntk`

I'm using Python 3.7 and windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

[`cntk` currently provides](https://pypi.org/project/cntk/2.6/#files) wheels for Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6, Linux 64 bit and w64. There is no source code hence there is no way to compile for Python 3.7.

You can try to install [from sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/bindings/python) or use Python 3.6.

Comment: I uninstalled python 3.7, and tried installing it with 3.6.6, but it's giving me  
 `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install cntk'`

Comment: I don't see anything about 3.6 in `c:\python37\ `.